# How to center a text label without much movement when it changes?

Tags: fonts, alignment, ios

I have a text block that I need to center horizontaly, however when it changes, it moves a bit, and I don't quite like it. A similar counter in iPhone countdown app somehow manages to avoid this problem.
How would you suggest to handle it? I guess it can be solved with another font, but I like current one and I wonder if there some other design approaches for things like that.

[image]

Comment: Is it a part of some iOS app?

Comment: You could use a monospace (at least for the number characters) font or more "manually" fix the colon in place (the other spacing would be arguably off in that case). Another option is to animate the change in position so it's less noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for this.

Either you use a monospaced font (or even some non-mono fonts have tabular numbers that solve this issue)

The other option is to make it appear centre aligned even though it technically is not. So you could have the ":" at a fixed position, the "1" right aligned and the "41" left aligned. This of course is pretty hard to do if you want to code this responsively...

Comment: Why would this be hard to code? Do you mean that the api has no way of querrying width of text?

Comment: @joojaa  If you have a fixed width it is easy. 
But with flexible width it could be a little more tricky – not rocket science either though. You essentially need 3 div's with fixed widths and a wrapper that is centred. The tricky part is to make sure that the text never overflows and spacings remain balanced etc.

Comment: Lots of things that could break this...
– Font-size media queries need to be accounted for
– What when user zooms
– What if there are also bigger numbers like 1000:41 (then would not be in center and probably overflowing)  
– Later font size changes
– etc.

Comment: Everything breaks if you push it hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **tabular lining**. It's where all the numbers take up the same space, regardless of their glyphs' size--similar to how a monospaced font would act.

In css you can use `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;`However it may not work on every font, I think it requires OpenType format and require the font creator added the functionality.

If you right aligned the type, and were able to set that css property, it should behave how you'd want.

Mozilla: "tabular-nums activating the set of figures where numbers are all of the same size, allowing them to be easily aligned like in tables. It corresponds to the OpenType values tnum."

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric

Visual Example:
[image]